# iphone addressbook saving link to a contact

Tags: iphone, addressbook, abrecord

in my iphone app, I'm wishing to link a contact to a data-piece in an array. All the data handling is fine. My question is: what contact info parameter can be saved in a database, acting as a link to a contact. Then later I will be able to call this one value and then get the link back to the contact.

---EDIT BELOW

This is where I am up to, but I just cant get it right yet. I get the contact view sliding over, but it contains an empty contact. Can someone please help.

```
ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

int referenceid = 69249600;


ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, referenceid);
//ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID()

pvc.displayedPerson = person;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];  
NSLog(@"customerRecID %d", pvc.displayedPerson);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ABRecordID is what you want to use. Not sure what you mean by "call this as a variable". If you want to convert an ABRecordRef to an ABRecordID, use ABRecordGetRecordID().

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you want convert a record to a record ID, use the above function. To go the other way, use ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID()

Comment: i reposted my current problem, can you see a fix?

Comment: Where are you getting referenceid from?

Comment: ben, i posted my full problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138923/iphone-addressbook-getting-null-item-in-abaddressbookgetpersonwithrecordid